# Propositional statements

Tags: logic

If we look at the statement $P(n)$ : $n$ is divisible by $2$, we know that for all integers $n$ its false, but its true for even $n$. Now, am I allowed to write $P$ at $n=3$, to get $P(3) : 3$ is divisible by $2$ which we know not  to be true. Now my question is, can I evaluate $P$ for any integer $n$? Or can I only evaluate it for $n$ such that it's true?

Comment: This is a statement that depends on $n$. You can evaluate it for any $n$ but it won't always be a true statement.

Comment: Alright, that is where my confusion with induction was, and now it all makes so much sense, is there a way we can write this? What I mean by that is, we can say $\forall n \in {N}: P(n)$ when its true for all $n$ natural, can we write "We can evaluate the statement for all natural $n$" like this?

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little;

What you've written is an *open sentence* over a domain $\mathcal{D}$. That is, a declarative sentence with one (or more) variables in the domain.

Now the truth value is dependent on the value of $n$.

We know that the statement $P(n)$ is true if we take $\mathcal{D} = \{2k | k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and we know it to be false if $\mathcal{D} = \{2k+1 | k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (the odd numbers are not divisible by 2).

For any other set (as domain), or value you can determine the truth value of the statement.

**Edit**

You can write statements with quantifiers such as $\forall$ and $\exists$.
It is important to form correct sentences with a truth value (and in most texts that are written these the usage of most logic symbols is not advised). The example you provided: $\forall x, (x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1$ would be better if you specified the set of which $x$ is an element to determine the truth value of the statement.

Mabye it's good to look at a few examples.

Lets look at the statement:
\begin{align}\label{tag1} \tag{*}
\text{for every two real numbers $x$ and $y$, $x^2+y^2 \geq 0$} 
\end{align}
We can let $P(x,y) : x^2+y^2\geq 0$, meaning that we have 'defined' the open sentence. Now we want to write \eqref{tag1} with the logic symbols:
\begin{align}\label{**}\tag{**}
\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, P(x,y) 
\end{align}
This is a truth statement. Since $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $y^2 \geq 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we can see that \eqref{tag1} is a true statement.

If we take $x=k+1$ where $k\in \mathbb{R}$ then this statement will still be true since $x$ will still be an element of $\mathbb{R}$ and the statement was true for **all** $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Notice however, that this statement is **not** true for $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$, for if we take $x=y=i$ then $x^2+y^2 = i^2+i^2 = -1 + (-1) = -2$ which is not greater than zero. So it is important to specify what set your element are from

**Sidenote**
Many authors do not use the notation $n=k$ and $n=k+1$. Many people say that induction can be summarized as:

For each positive integer $n$, let $P(n)$ be a statement. If

1. $P(1)$ is true and
2. for every natural number $k$, the implication $$\text{if}\:\: P(k) \:\:\text{ then}\:\: P(k+1)$$
   is true, (notice that this implication has a truth value as well, it is in itself a statement) then $P(n)$ is true for every postivie integer $n$.

Notice that we are not reffering to $n=...$, even though that is implicity what this statement says.
The authors from the link also do not use the $n=...$ notation, but they just use $n=1$ and the statement $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147769/discussion-on-answer-by-josef-k-propositional-statements); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.